# What will happen to our pro term moderators after the upcoming election?

Tags: discussion, election, moderation

Will the pro term (beta) ♦ moderators stay on as full moderators after the election? If not, are they permitted to run again?

Comment: FWIW, I'd be fine with them staying. I think the current mods are doing a great job. (All of the candidates at this point also look awesome...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pro-tem moderators have to nominate themselves for the election if they want to stay moderators. They don't keep the diamond automatically.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wonder what's the reason though. Is it because the pro tem mods aren't 'democratically elected'?

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani precisely. Pro-tem mods are appointed by SE. When a site graduates, it should get to vote for its mods just like a real adult.